# Mapserver MapFile label at polygons, how to say "not repeat"?

Tags: mapserver, labeling, mapfile

I am using Mapserver v5.6 and used MapFile with 2 layers. One layer to show polygon and other to show label at ST_PointOnSurface of the same polygon... **There are another way to show unique-label** at POSITION CC of the polygon?

I tested `REPEATDISTANCE 9999`  but no effect.

Even [Mapserver v6 documentation](http://mapserver.org/mapfile/label.html) have no instruction about "no-repeat" options.

The polygon-layer was tested (with no effect) with this mapfile fragment for label

```
      LABEL
        ALIGN center
        FONT "ubuntu"
        TYPE TRUETYPE
        SIZE 15
        POSITION CC
        COLOR 255 0 0
        REPEATDISTANCE 9999
        OUTLINECOLOR 50 200 60
      END #label
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your mapfile. It should work.

```
LAYER
-------
POSTLABELCACHE FALSE
PROCESSING "LABEL_NO_CLIP=ON"
LABELCACHE ON
-----
    LABEL 
      -------
      PARTIALS TRUE
      MINDISTANCE 50
      REPEATDISTANCE 9999
      --------
    END    
END
```

Comment: This is a correct answer but I only added the processing directive. This caused the label to be positioned on centroid of feature.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is at the `LAYER` level. It's a processing directive called `LABEL_NO_CLIP`. This make sure that the polygon is not clipped between tile so the label doesn't repeat.

```
LAYER
  NAME ...
  PROCESSING "LABEL_NO_CLIP=True"
  ...
  CLASS
    ...
    LABEL
      ALIGN center
      FONT "ubuntu"
      TYPE TRUETYPE
      SIZE 15
      POSITION CC
      COLOR 255 0 0
      OUTLINECOLOR 50 200 60
    END #label
```